# GWT or JavaFX webpage dilemma

Tags: java, gwt, javafx

Im trying to resolve following dilemma. I have to develop whole webpage system(with user friendly content management, it should look like very simple Drupal or Joomla) as a project to school. The webpage should have function of adding and removing articles, editing menus, editing whole webpage layout(header position, menu position etc).

Im in phase of deciding which system would be the best for this purpose. I wrote several applications in GWT. It's very quick to develop something, it works on Tomcat etc. So it could be very good adept for this task. But recently I got an idea of writing whole webpage system in JavaFX 2.0 (webpage would open inside the browser).

What is your opinion about this fact ?  Should I use JavaFX or GWT? I'm not sure if whole webpage will be quick enough in JavaFX. If the users that will be visiting this page wont have problems with launching this page etc. I havent found any information about this on the internet.

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go for GWT (also consider using Vaadin or SmartGWT). It does not require a Java Virtual Machine to be installed on the client. Also, GWT allows the client to download only small pieces of the application, and not the whole thing.

You cited two Content Management Systems like Drupal and Joomla that are written in PHP, so maybe the best solution for you is a CMS written in java like [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) or [Magnolia](http://www.magnolia-cms.com/).

Comment: I ve tested a little these two ones that you posted and they look fine so I will definitely go for GWT :) thanks for answer :)

Comment: I can think of numerous reasons to choose GWT over JavaFX for this particular task, but runtime speed would not be one of them.  Do you have a reference to some performance tests showing GWT much faster than JavaFX?  It seems odd that JavaFX would be slower than GWT as JavaFX can display GWT in a WebView.  So if JavaFX were slower than GWT than it would end up slower than itself - which doesn't make much sense.  Or perhaps you meant faster in some other context, e.g. development speed for a web based interface?

Comment: @jewelsea I corrected my answer. I didn't mean runtime speed. Maybe the best runtime speed is with CGI and C language: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html A good JavaFX application is heavier to download than a single GWT web page. Plus, GWT does not require a JVM on the client.

Comment: Thanks for clarification and updating your answer vitalik.

Comment: the fact of downloading the JVM could be a siginficant problem. Becuase if i imagine a customer that wants to get the content as fast as possible ... it wouldnt work fine if he had to download Runtime Environment etc. Furthermore I had some problems sometimes with downloading the right version of JRE. So it could make this contraproductive. But if FX worked as GWT workes itd been great :)

Comment: Since JavaFX is java code, why couldn't I use JavaFX elements for my application and then have GWT convert that to JavaScript?

Comment: @JadieldeArmas even if you can compile Java code into JavaScript with GWT, you will not have the same UI components: buttons, sliders, pictures have a specific GWT configuration that cannot be ported from JavaFX

Answer (score 1):

do you want to do a web page or an applicatin for one plugin ? GWT of course.

Comment: i want to do a content management system ... so web page with some management interface :) so GWT would be better :) thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

**GWT**

GWT follows a most innovative approach: you write the entire application in Java. But it’s executed in Javascript. A good portion of your code is cross-compiled to Javascript and uploaded to the client.
Judging from the presentations I’ve seen, this approach works surprisingly good. In former times the GWT compiler used to be slow, but today, they seem to have solved (or at least alleviated) the problem. As far as I can see, GWT is an excellent choice

**javafx**

JavaFX 2.0 is a pretty new GUI framework. So expect a few glitches. The good news is that it’s likely to improve over the years. And I suppose people will start to write JavaFX component frameworks if JavaFX is going to be popular.
There’s a video showing the domain of JavaFX very clearly.
[Container terminal monitoring with 3D JavaFX](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AS26gZrYNy8) 
[Source](http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/hottest-gui-framework-java-world-jsf-javafx/)

Comment: You forgot to add the source of your answer... http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/hottest-gui-framework-java-world-jsf-javafx/